# Copy selected content to input text box in dialog box TinyMCE plugin

Tags: angular, tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I want to copy the selected content from the editor to a textbox in dialog box in a custom plugin

```
return editor.windowManager.open({
  title: 'Example plugin',
  body: {
    type: 'panel',
    items: [
      {
        type: 'input',
        name: 'title',
        label: 'Title'
      }
    ]
  },
  buttons: [
    {
      type: 'cancel',
      text: 'Close'
    },
    {
      type: 'submit',
      text: 'Save',
      primary: true
    }
  ],
  onSubmit: function (api) {
    var data = api.getData();
    // Insert content when the window form is submitted
    editor.insertContent('Title: ' + data.title);
    api.close();
  }
});
```

};

Now i want to get the a selected content ( editor.selection.getContent()) and load it to input field name'title'. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `editor.windowManager.open()` is a Dialog Instance API, which has a `setData` method.

```
tinymce.init({
selector: '#textarea',
setup: function(editor) {
 editor.ui.registry.addButton('example_button', {
  icon: 'embed-page',
  onAction: function() {
   var api=editor.windowManager.open(dialogConfig);
   var data=api.getData();
   var selectedNode = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getNode();
   // do it here 
   data.title=selectedNode.innerHTML();
   api.setData(data);
  }
 }
}
})
```

The code gets the API of the dialog opened by clicking the toolbar button, and uses `setData` to save the data tructure in dialog instance (see `initialData`, `getData()`,`setData()` in Dialog UI docs https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/ui-components/dialog/#dialogdataandstate ). This is the connection between the form and the selected object.